# Transformer symmetrical supply

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I have a transformer that has only one secondary voltage and I don't have a center-tapped transformer or a transformer that has two secondary voltages.

Is there a way to make a symmetrical supply using only one secondary voltage (two cables)?

It should be for 60W(24V, 2.5A)

Comment: Interesting, but i want a transformer to have max 24V output

Comment: With 24V/2.5A winding you can get ±12V at best, or slightly less with active rail splitter. Or you can get ±24V with an extra inverting buck-boost, for example. Note that, for fully utilisation of the winding you may require an LC filter (with a large L) after rectification. Otherwise the DC current would be almost half the RMS current drawn from the winding.

Comment: Interesting, thank's for idea !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

Maybe even multiple ways depending on what you need it for.

Just use two resistors and you have a center tap. It cannot handle large currents so it is generally buffered somehow.

You could also use one AC wire as the ground, and half-wave rectify the other wire separately into positive and negative supplies.

Or use a DC/DC converter that can take in the single ended supply and provide any kind of output you want.

Comment: "You could also use one AC wire as the ground, and half-wave rectify the other wire separately into positive and negative supplies." - For what power is this rated, beause as you said I can make it using resistors but its not for big load.

Comment: @Anton same as anything else half-wave rectifed. But both ways. Or actually, it is called "full wave voltage doubler". I don't know what transformer you have but either it can or cannot power your load, and you may need another transformer anyway. And the load is also unknown. We don't know what you are powering and with what. They could be incompatible.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I want it for amplifier.

Comment: @Anton So what is the transformer capable of (voltage and current) and what does the amplifier require? What amplifier it is, are there diagrams or manuals etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this type of voltage doubler. It has a little higher voltage ripple (only half periode supplies single cap), so you must use a bigger caps compared to full wave rectifier.

[image]

Comment: Would it be good for amplifier ?

Comment: Well, it certainly do the job, but require a big capacity caps to maintain small voltage ripple. It would be good make LC fitering, not a C only.

Comment: Okay interesting, thanks!